# jQuery crashing IE

Tags: jquery

I have a website that is crashing internet explorer on certain users computers. I'm lucky enought hat a few people h\ve contacted me to tell me otherwise i wouldnt know anuthing about it.

It doesnt happen on everyones PC so I'm a bit lost as to what is causing IE to crash. The website uses jquery 1.4.2. What is the best way ot trapping the error so i can find out what's going on?

Thanks
Al

Comment: A plugin could also be the reason why IE crashes only on some pc's.

Answer (score 1):

First, find a computer where you can reproduce the problem. Compare browser versions and Windows versions.

Microsoft has a [Script debugger](https://web.archive.org/web/20151010141059/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx) that is actually pretty good once you get it running, but in this case, a more primitive but simple and effective method is to put an `alert()` into the source code until the point is reached where things crash.

Comment: @NimChimpsky - it may not crash with the debugger attached, IE changes several behaviors when this happens.

Comment: Hi Pekka - my problem is more that I can't find a PC that this happens on. I'm guessing that even a try catch block wont help me iof its compltely crashing IE...?

Comment: @Nim @higgsy I added info about the debugger but I would prefer the `alert()` method for this because it's way simpler, and as @Nick says the crash may not occur. As to how to find a computer, ask the people reporting the problem about their exact browser and Windows versions (including Service Packs). Other than that, I think the best you can do is go through your code and look for errors. For example, a broken selector statement in jQuery can make a browser crash sometimes (I had this a few days today with a misspelt `$("[type=text]")`, although that was in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pekka,

Some code is crashing some IE's, and you need to find where it is.

I suggest alert('bla bla'); method to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are they seeing the crash on? IE6 is notorious for crashing on even simple css or HTML, such as these:

```
<style>*{position:relative}</style><table><input></table>
```

or

```
<script>for (x in document.write) document.write(x);</script>
```